# Converting from byte array to short producing wrong negative value

Tags: java, endianness

It's been a while since I've done operations at the bit/byte level so please forgive me if this is simple.

I'm receiving data over a TCP socket in a Java application from an embedded device.  The data is little endian (least significant byte first) and I'm currently trying to grab `short` values out of an array of data.  To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
byte[] valBytes = {data[0], data[1]};
short val = EndianArrayUtils.getShortFromLittleEndianRange(valBytes);
```

This works fine for positive numbers, but when the `short` should be -1, I'm getting -2 instead.  The data that produces -2 is:

```
byte[] valBytes = {(byte)0xff, (byte)0xff};
short val = EndianArrayUtils.getShortFromLittleEndianRange(valBytes);
```

Am I missing something?  -1 in two's complement should be `11111111 11111111` correct?

**Edit**

I completely forgot that I was the one that actually wrote `EndianArrayUtils`. The code for the `getShortFromLittleEndianRange` method is

```
public static short getShortFromLittleEndianRange(byte[] range){
        return (short)((short)(range[1] >> 8) + (short)(range[0]));
    }
```

Obviously there's something wrong with how that's operating on negative numbers.

Comment: Where's EndianArrayUtils from? And you're right, -1 should be ffff, I guess the utils fail a shift, when converting to short. Is the EndianArrayUtils from some library?? If not, can you show some code from it?

Comment: @Fildor I'm an idiot.  I wrote `EndianArrayUtils` a long time ago and forgot about it.  I had since thought it was a java class haha.  Let me get that code and post it.

Comment: :) That's nothing to call one's self an idiot for. It's a sign of good interface, isn't it?

Comment: @Fildor maybe...if it works ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I would use ByteBuffer

```
byte[] valBytes = {(byte)0xff, (byte)0xff};
short s = ByteBuffer.wrap(valBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort();
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
-1
```

If you read into a ByteBuffer you don't need the `byte[]` at all.

To fix your example

```
public static short getShortFromLittleEndianRange(byte[] range){
    return (short)((range[1] << 8) + (range[0] & 0xff));
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I just switched to that after @Fildor helped me discover that I had written `EndianArrayUtils` myself.  It does seem to be slower than the byte shifting etc. Is that accurate?  Is there a way to do it the way I was doing it?

Comment: Using the wrap() is slower. If you use ByteBuffer instead of using a `byte[]` only then is it faster.